# I got a error trying to compile VLC custom build (VVC) on macOS 11.4 with Xcode

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, vlc, macos-big-sur, libvlc

I need some help with custom VLC build. I am running on macOS 11.4 Big Sur (inside virtual machine), trying to compile my custom VLC build of VVC (known as Versatile Video Codec), I checked everything software’s like Python, macOS SDK, CMake, Java and XCode (latest version, December 2021) before compiling. I got an error for this:

```
Command CompileXIB failed with a nonzero exit code

/usr/local/libo266dec/contrib/contrib-x86_64-apple-darwin20/breakpad/src/client/mac/Breakpad.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.7, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9 to 12.2. (in target 'Breakpad' from project 'Breakpad')
/usr/local/libo266dec/contrib/contrib-x86_64-apple-darwin20/breakpad/src/client/mac/Breakpad.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.7, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9 to 12.2. (in target 'breakpadUtilities' from project 'Breakpad')
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileXIB /usr/local/libo266dec/contrib/contrib-x86_64-apple-darwin20/breakpad/src/client/mac/sender/Breakpad.xib (in target 'crash_report_sender' from project 'Breakpad')
(1 failure)
make: *** [.breakpad] Error 65
```

I followed the docs on https://github.com/TencentCloud/O266player
I tried build on macOS version of custom VLC, but it will not work.
Can you tell me why I got an error for this? Do I have to use previous version of macOS 10.15.6 and XCode 11.6, I don’t where is XCode old mirrors?

Also here's log file: https://pastebin.com/1gRZF1zz

Comment: https://github.com/TencentCloud/O266player/blob/master/extras/package/macosx/build.sh#L12  maybe needs to be updated as recent tools wont be able to target osx<10.9.

Comment: @RichardBarber I think the docs says it tested macOS 10.15.6 and Xcode 11.6 will work only, other versions won't work like Big Sur and Monterey.

Comment: Yeah, definitely be using the right sdk and specify it as the min macos version.

Comment: @RichardBarber Update, I tried built again, so I cloned repository of o266player, then I made build folder and I used code same as instructions of mac os code build. Here is a different error I got: https://pastebin.com/90n4gS1i